# Finding prime factors of large expression (without calculator)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Show that: $5^3(5^3(253)+3)+1 = 19 \times 251 \times 829$.

I tried setting $n=5$, so that $253 = 23 \times 11 = (4n+3)(2n+1)$ and going from there, but the resulting polynomial in $n$ was $8n^6 + 10n^7 + 3n^6 + 3n^3 + 1$, which turns out to be irreducible over the integers, so this doesn't help at all.

Comment: You tried setting $n=5$ in *what*? Also, your polynomial in $n$ is given in a strange manner.

Comment: I just set $n=5$ so that the expression could be rewritten as $n^3(n^3(4n+3)(2n+1)+3)+1$.

Comment: I think you meant to write $8n^8$ rather than $8n^6,$ for what it's worth.

Comment: Trying to set $n=5^3$ will help if you write $253=2\cdot5^3+3$ as $2n+3$. You have $2n^3+3n^2+3n+1=(2n+1)(n^2+n+1)$. Both $n^2+n+1$ and $n^6+n^3+1$ (if you set $n=5$ instead) are irreducible, so further factorization needs another trick,

Answer (score 0):

My eye is drawn to the $253$ in the expression being close to the factor $251$ and the fact that $5^3$ is very close to half of $251$.  Given the known result I would write
$$5^3(5^3(253)+3)+1=5^3(5^3\cdot (251+2)+3)+1\\=5^6\cdot 251+5^3\cdot253+1\\=(5^6+5^3+1)251$$
then just compute $5^6+5^3+1=15625+125+1=15751$ and divide by $19$

Answer (score -1):

Divide $19*251*829$ by $5$ and take remainders.

$19*251*829 = 19*250*829 + 19*830 -20 + 1=$

$5(19*50*829 + 19*166 -4) + 1=$

$5(19*50*829 + 19*165 + 20 -5) + 1=$

$5(19*10*829 + 19*33 + 3) + 1=$

$5^2(19*10*829 + 20*33 -30) + 1=$

$5^3(19*2*829 + 4*33 -6) + 1=$

$5^3(19*2*830 -20*2 + 2  + 5*33 - 30 - 3-6) + 1=$

$5^3(19*2*830 - 20*2 + 5*33 -30 -10 +3) + 1=$

$5^3(5(19*2*166 - 4*2 + 33 -8) +3) + 1=$

$5^3(5(19*2*165 + 20*2 -10 + 30 -5)+3) + 1=$

$5^3(5^2(19*2*33 + 4*2 + 3)+3) + 1=$

$5^3(5^2(19*2*33 + 11)+3) +1=$

$5^3(5^2(20*2*33 - 2*33+11)+3)+1=$

$5^3(5^2(20*2*33 - 2*30-6+11)+3)+1=$

$5^3(5^3(4*2*33 -2*6 +1)+3)+1=$

$5^3(5^3(5*2*33 - 2*30 - 3*5 -3 +1)+3)+1=$

$5^3(5^3(330 - 60 -15 -2)+3)+1=$

$5^3(5^3(253)+3)+1=$